# creating domain in ubuntu server 12.10

Tags: domain-server

I install ubuntu server 12.10 , I want to implement a domain on this server.
how can I implement domain ?
I read the document of samba but i think this cannot solve my problem .

Comment: You are more likely to get a helpful answer if you can provide enough information to answer your question. Please edit your question and provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish and exactly what steps you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of domain you want that cannot be set up with Samba... If I get you right, you probably want some fancy active directory domain, which can be accomplished with either **Samba 3** (very complicated) or **Samba 4** (still pretty complicated, but easier).

If you want to try Samba 4, I recommend using [this](http://www.enterprisesamba.com/samba4app/) appliance from SerNet, which I recently used to set up an active directory domain.